# Bat file - not finding .exe

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

If I create an .exe file with Visual Studio 2010 (in the bin/Debug folder) is it possible to use a bat file to start this program?

I tried the below in my bat file:

```
start "c:\Services\ServicesChecker\ServicesChecker\bin\Debug" ServicesChecker.exe
```

however when I run it, it says Windows cannot find ServicesChecker.exe even though if I browse to the location I can see it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your command, the `"c:\Services\..."` is the title given to the window, and is not used to find the executable.

Try:

```
start c:\Services\ServicesChecker\ServicesChecker\bin\Debug\ServicesChecker.exe
```

Comment: @aix - Cheers - another thing - if I want to pass arguments to this program do you know how I can do that in the .bat file (i.e - the prgoram will expect a few strings and an int coming in - Thanks

Comment: You can pass arguments with a space after the exe then the argument value, e.g. ServicesChecker.exe arg1 arg2

Answer (score 2):

Its because there is no option in start by which you can specify the path.

Use

```
start "c:\Services\ServicesChecker\ServicesChecker\bin\Debug\ServicesChecker.exe"
```

this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try just using the file path rather than `start`, and you need to include the filename in the same quoted path, like this:

```
"c:\Services\ServicesChecker\ServicesChecker\bin\Debug\ServicesChecker.exe"
```